# XlsxWriter: specifying plot style in terms of Excel 2016 designs

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a certain style of plot in Excel 2016 (version is important), using Python and XlsxWriter module. A reproducible code example that we could use can be found here: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_simple.html.

**Intended result**

What I would like to have is the graph styled as using `Style 3` (for example) in Excel 2016, which can be selected from the `Design` menu that appears upon clicking on the graph. Note that I added data labels, but these are irrelevant to the question:

[image: desired result]

**Steps already made**

From the documentation of XlsxWriter becomes apparent that the method `chart.set_style()` (http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#set_style) is probably what we need. Unfortunately, this method doesn't seem to manipulate styles in terms of Excel 2016. Rather it seems to affect color schemes that in Excel 2016 are found under the menu `Design -> Change colors`, e.g.:

[image]

or even produce some other styles which I presume may come from earlier Excel versions, as these do not seem to be implemented as pre-set styles in Excel 2016, e.g.:

[image]

I wonder if it possible somehow to set plot styles specific to Excel 2016 in some way. Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [set_style()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-style) docs:

> **Note**
>
> In Excel 2013 the Styles section of the 'Design' tab in Excel shows what were referred to as 'Layouts; in previous versions of Excel. These layouts are not defined in the file format. They are a collection of modifications to the base chart type. They can be replicated using the XlsxWriter Chart API but they cannot be defined by the `set_style()` method.

This applies to Excel 2016 as well.

So unfortunately there is no quick single method call to get the format that you need. You will need to figure out the style elements that Excel applies and applies them via the XlsxWriter APIs. Almost of the Excel Chart formatting is available in XlsxWriter.

Comment: Thanks for answering this so promptly.